# Difference between "пасть" and "упасть"

Tags: лексикон

I found a source saying that the perfective counterpart of падать is both упасть and пасть, so I was wondering what the difference between these two words is.

So far I could only find a post explaining the difference between падать and упасть (the first one is imperfective and the second one is perfective) but I couldn't find anything on the difference between пасть and упасть (though упасть seems to be more commonly used).

Comment: Wiktionary article on [пасть](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/пасть#пасть_II) gives a good summary of its use cases out of which i'd single out 2, 6 & 7 as belonging to active use, but be mindful that the word itself belongs to a higher register so isn't typical to everyday speech

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I believe this comment (slightly improved) should be posted as an answer.

Comment: also worth noting as reflected by the tags of the Wiktionary article, this word is used predominantly figuratively, and is a fossilized part of such stable collocations as **низко пасть** and **пасть в бою** explained in  Nikolay Ershov's response

Comment: @Dmitry there's almost zero of my own input in the comment so i don't think it qualifies as a proper answer

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка If your post answers the question - it is a good answer. Even if it contains only quotes and [references](https://russian.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 8):

**Пасть** came to be a lofty metaphorical term, covering probably all cases where falling is used as a lofty metaphor:

- of a slain combatant (**пасть в бою**);
- of a city, kingdom, etc. (**Рим пал**);
- of an overthrown ruler (**тиран пал**);
- of decline into depravity (**как низко ты пал!**).

**Упасть** is for everyday falls, mostly literal, but also e.g. of stocks or currencies.

Like the imperfective **падать**, the verbal noun **падение** is shared between the two.

Answer (score 1):

friend. If we are talking about пасть as about a verb this word should be understood as a sublime and outdated word something like "face downwards" in front of powerful person - пасть ниц. Although, it is really rare in common life
But if пасть is a noun we translate it as "jaws".
Prefixes are probably the most important thing in Russian because they change a verb absolutely. Some examples:
Быть           to be
Прибыть    to arrive

Бежать      to run
Забежать  to make a short visit

Знать         to know
Узнать       to recognize 
Признать  to admit

I really hope that I helped you.